# discord.py: Is there anything that could be making it where kick/ban commands don't work?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am trying to code a Discord bot and I would like to add commands so that people with kick/ban permissions can use the kick/ban commands. I have added many different forms of kick and ban commands, but none of them function correctly. I am absolutely positive the kick/ban commands were correct. I am starting to get the feeling that there is something is wrong with the rest of my code, making it where kick/ban commands don't function.

Here is what I currently have:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import logging


# Enables logging
logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)


# Assigns the Discord client to a variable called client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')


# Loads .env
load_dotenv()


# Prints a message stating that the bot is loggen in
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

# Prints the help message when a user says $help
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$help'):
        await message.channel.send('''**Hydra Help**
*This message contains a list of commands and what they do.*

__help__: Prints this message.''')


# Starts the bot
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Is there anything wrong with my code so far that may be causing kick/ban commands to not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108340/how-to-kick-users-on-command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kick users on command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108340/how-to-kick-users-on-command)

Answer (score -2):

You have to just do this:

Kick:

```
await ???(For example member or ctx.author).kick(reason=???)
```

Ban:

```
await ???(For example member or ctx.author).ban(reason=???)
```