# kick is undefined in discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I made a bot that kicks people when pinging @everyone on discord but the problem is that I get this error

```
NameError: name 'kick' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('@everyone'):
        await kick(message.author,reason = "spam")

client.run('censored for obvious reasons')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kick users on command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108340/how-to-kick-users-on-command)

Comment: isn't it supposed to be included in discord library?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be in the global namespace, as you've tried to reference it here. Have you read [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.kick)? `kick` is a method available on the `Guild` object - is that what you're trying to use?

Comment: oh  thanks, I'm new to this

Comment: @JohnDoe Please check the answer below. That is best explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments were already quite informative, but here is a possible solution anyway, in case others stumble across this "error".

Your information is not correct, but you have already provided all the information we need, only these must be changed in the arrangement.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('@everyone'):
        await message.author.kick(reason="Spam")
```

- Here we get the `message.author` and `kick` him for the `reason="Spam"`
- An `await kick` does not work here, because the bot does not know who to kick, even if you have already specified `message.author` as the person to be kicked. It's just the wrong arrangement.