# How do you create a kick command in discord python?

Tags: python, discord.py

@client.command doesnt work so i tried doing

```
if message.content.startswith(f'-kick {member}'):
      member.ban()
      await message.channel.send(f'User {member} has been kicked')
```

pls help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kick users on command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108340/how-to-kick-users-on-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well using on_message for kick command would be harder so try using a client.command
like this:

```py
@client.command() # command decorator
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member): # kick function
  await ctx.guild.kick(member) # kicks the member from the guild that the command was used in
  await ctx.send(f"User {member} has been kicked") # telling that the member has been kicked
```

you can add a reason by adding another argument if you want

Comment: how do you know if the message is a command or not? i tried using my prefix but it displayed nothing on the server and console

Comment: What do you mean @H1387XD? You have to define your bot using the line ```bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="<your prefix here>")```

Comment: i used that line but how does @bot.command() knows if its a command or just a normal message

Comment: UPDATE: i figured out i have to remove on_message for it to work properly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just using a `member.ban()` instead `member.kick()`, it's simple

```
if message.content.startswith(f'-kick {member}'):
  member.kick()
  await message.channel.send(f'User {member} has been kicked')
```