# AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'kick'

Tags: python, discord

So I have done tons of research, found many answers, but none of them worked. I am trying to get my bot to kick a user on command, but I don't know the proper syntax. Help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '#kick' in message.content.lower():
        mod=discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, name='Mod')
        if mod in message.author.roles:
            await message.channel.send('Who do you want to kick?')
            try:
                message=await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author==message.author and m.channel==message.channel, timeout=15)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.channel.send('Your victim got away')
            else:
                member2id=message.mentions[0].id
                member2=await bot.fetch_user(member2id)
                await member2.kick()
                await message.channel.send(f'{message.content} was kicked')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('You dont have the permission to use that command')
bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108340/how-to-kick-users-on-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`Member.kick`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=kick#discord.Member.kick), as opposed to `User.kick` (which does not exist).

I believe `message.mentions` returns a list of `Member` objects, so the snippet might be:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '#kick' in message.content.lower():
        mod=discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, name='Mod')
        if mod in message.author.roles:
            await message.channel.send('Who do you want to kick?')
            try:
                message=await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author==message.author and m.channel==message.channel, timeout=15)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await message.channel.send('Your victim got away')
            else:
                await message.mentions[0].kick()
                await message.channel.send(f'{message.content} was kicked')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('You dont have the permission to use that command')
bot.run('token')
```

However, note that [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=mentions#discord.Message.mentions) can be empty, and that the list is randomly ordered.

Alternatively, `discord.py` supports more `kick` functions, see them [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=kick).

Comment: I'm trying it now

Comment: It works now, thank you. But does this mean that I can type await message.mentions[0].ban()? Does that work too?

Comment: My advise is to just type `ban` into the discordpy documentation search field [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=ban). And yes, that link contains `Member.ban`, so it seems to be a function. I reckon it would work then.